# Definition of "reentrant function"

Tags: function, concurrency, interrupt, conceptual, reentrancy

I have seen several posts asking for, or answered with, explanations of what is reentrancy, but none requesting a precise definition, so here goes:

What is the precise definition of the concept of "reentrant function"?

Answer (score 0):

From my current understanding, I would propose the following definition.

A function F is *reentrant* if and only if the following holds for function F:

For any two calls A and B of F, if

- condition 1) call B begins after call A has started but before it has finished

and

- condition 2) call A resumes only after call B has finished

and

- condition 3) both calls A and B would have succeeded (*) if isolated

, then, in the absence of interfering external events (e.g. power cut, seg fault in an unrelated thread, etc.)

- guarantee 1) call A is guaranteed to *succeed*(*)

and

- guarantee 2) call B is guaranteed to *succeed*(*)

(*) read *succeed* = *finish and yield correct results and side effects*

Notice this is not enough for thread safety, since it offers no guarantees of what happens when call A resumes *before* call B has finished.

Answer (score 0):

A function is reentrant if it can be called at the same time by different threads by having the same behavior and result as if it is call by only one thread.

Comment: Not true: a function that can be interrupted and called again in the interrupt handler need not satisfy your thread-safety requirement and is still reentrant

Answer (score 0):

There is no single definition of "reentrant"; it depends on the context.  In particular, the C++ standard doesn't mention it at all. It generally means that a function has well-defined behavior when called by several threads simultaneously, with or without some locking required, but it may also mean e.g. that a function can be called by the same thread again recursively. The concept of reentrancy may apply to other things besides functions, e.g. in the C standard you find the text:

> The lock is reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.

Comment: I am not so sure it depends on the context. I would be more inclined to simply think people use it with different meanings because they don't understand it. When applied to other things than functions, the meaning is somehow derived from the meaning of reentrant function (in your lock example, you could equivalently say that a lock is reentrant if the locking mechanism itself is reentrant)

Comment: So is this function reentrant?  `unsigned f(){ static unsigned x=0; x += rand(); return x; }`?  Is it reentrant if I replace `unsigned x` by `atomic<unsigned> x`?  I don't think you will find agreement about this question among any group of developers.

Comment: The 1st version is not reentrant because an interrupt that calls `f` again may result in undefined behavior; if you have `x` atomic, I'd say it is unclear whether or not `f` is reentrant only in the same sense that it is unclear what _correctness_ is for `f`. If you say that f is correct if the nth evaluation of `f()` yields a random number that is less than the (n+1)th evaluation, and considering the index of an evaluation to be in the order the evaluations complete, then I think most people would agree the version with atomic is reentrant (assuming an atomic operation cannot be interrupted).